# the apparent distance created by an angle, the "size" of an angle in 3D space

Tags: single-word-requests

I can measure things in the distance, like really tall buildings, by pinching my fingers in front of my eyes.

The "perceived distance" between my thumb and forefinger is the same as the "perceived distance" between the ground and the top of the skyscraper.

E.g.

[image]

Even though in reality the pen is much closer to the laptop than it is to the guitar, the guitar and the laptop are the same angle from my eyes, so are two-dimensionally equidistant from the pen.

What is the name of the length of this two-dimensional line created by an angle in 3D space?

---

Apparently the angle is called the angular diameter, [wikipedia has this pic](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_diameter):

[image]

I want the name of d/2. Wikipedia (on that page) called d the diameter, but I bet there's a more specific term.

Comment: It’s called *apparent size*, and some other names: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_diameter . It’s usually measured in arcseconds (depending on magnitude): https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minute_and_second_of_arc .

Comment: @DanBron that's not quite what I want. I edited question

Comment: Dude, the opening paragraph of the article where you got that image ends with this bolded sentence: ***Angular radius** equals half the angular diameter*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Angular radius** equals half the angular diameter

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_diameter